# Progress bar doesn´t show progress if not full

Tags: java, javafx

this is in the css file

```
.yellow-bar { -fx-accent: yellow; }
.orange-bar{ -fx-accent: orange;}
.blue-bar{ -fx-accent: cyan;}
```

It show correctly the progress bar when its full but when it isnt it just appears with no progress!

```
 double pro2 = obsModel.getCurrentShield()/obsModel.getMaxShield();
            ColoredProgressBar pbShield = new ColoredProgressBar("blue-bar",pro2);

class ColoredProgressBar extends ProgressBar {
        ColoredProgressBar(String styleClass, double progress) {
            super(progress);
            getStyleClass().add(styleClass);
        }
```

Bars when its full1
[image: When bars are full!]

Bars when they're not full!
[image: Doesn't show]

Any idea why it won't show the progress when the progress isnt 1(100%) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the obsModel.getCurrentShield() and obsModel.getMaxShield() are integers, result will be either 0 or 1.
If so, just cast one of them to double:

double pro2 = (double) obsModel.getCurrentShield()/obsModel.getMaxShield()

Comment: That wouldnt do the trick but ... double pro2 =( (double) obsModel.getCurrentShield()/(double) obsModel.getMaxShield()) 
This did thanks mate!